# callback function not called in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have written a callback method in angularjs. But somehow, it is not called. My code is as follows.

Link function:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.getContent = function(itemId) {
                getTocService.getArtData(itemId, function(data){
                    var art = data;
                    alert(art);
                });
            }
element.append("<collection collection='member.tocItem'></collection>");    
                $compile(element.contents())(scope)
            }
```

Service:

app.service(
        "getTocService",
        function( $http, $q ) {
            return({

```
            getArtData: getArtData
        });

        function getToc(bookIdvar) {
            var request = $http({
                method: "post",
                url: "http://10.132.241.41:8082/apdpoc/services/ApdBookService/getTOC",
                params: {
                    action: "post"
                },
                data: {
                    getTOCCriteria:{
                    bookId: bookIdvar
                    }
                }
            });
            return( request.then(handleSuccess,handleError));
        }

        function getArtData(itemId, cb) {
            var request = $http({
                method: "post",
                url: "http://10.132.241.41:8082/apdpoc/services/ApdBookService/getArticle",
                params: {
                    action: "post"
                },
                data: {
                    getArticleCriteria:{
                    articleId: itemId,
                    locale: "en_US"
                    }
                }
            });
            return(request.then(handleSuccess,handleError), cb);
        }
        function handleSuccess(response){
            return (response.data);
        }

        function handleError( response ) {

            if (
                ! angular.isObject(response.data) ||
                ! response.data.message
                ) {
                return($q.reject("An unknown error occurred."));
            }
            return($q.reject(response.data.message));
        }

    }
```

);

As per my little knowledge on angularJs,
the call back method should execute

var art = data;
alert(art);

these lines. but control is not coming over there. Can someone let me know what is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update

```
return(request.then(handleSuccess,handleError), cb);
```

to

```
return(request.then(cb,handleError));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. it is working. Can you please let me know whether I can assign value to $scope variable inside link function?

Comment: Good to hear that. Yes you can do that.